# How to reflect changes from other property to a property in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

My target is create a custom view like UISlider. In my custom view, I use `IBDesignable` and `IBInspectable` to make it show up in Interface Builder.

If you look at a UISlider in Interface Builder:

[image: UISlider]

You can see if I change its `Value` to be greater than its `Maximum`, the `Maximum`automatically update its value in the Interface Builder.

My question is: How to make a property (like `Maximum`) change its value when I change value of other properties (like `Value`) in Interface Builder?

Thank in advance!

EDIT: Here is my current implementation:

[image: Implementation]

Current result:

[image: Current output]

You can see when `Minimum` value changed, value of `Value` also change but its value in the attribute inspector doesn't change.

Comment: didSet { and update value then?

Comment: I'm afraid didSet is called later in runtime, not in the moment you change it in the IB

Comment: Thank guys. I added more information to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing and I'm afraid we are currently not able to do stuff like that in the Interface Builder. Even when your @IBInspectable has a default value, IB ignores it and doesn't show it. The value is not specified ("--") until you set it.

@IBInspectable is currently (Xcode8.3) just a little bit nicer way how to set "User defined runtime attributes". These attributes are applied to the view during NIB loading using KVC.

**tl;dr** I think there's currently no (official) way how to do what you want.

EDIT: This, of course, doesn't prevent you from doing what you're doing. Everything will work as expected using didSet. You just won't have the instant response in IB.